# How to change the "shape" of pairplot in Seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, shapes, pairplot

I plotted this pairplot correlating only one features with all the others, how can i visualize it in a better way? I need to visualize 4 columns. In the official documentation of pairplot i can't find the option.

This is the df:
[image: This is the df]

This is the part of the code:

```
sns.pairplot(data=dftrain,
              y_vars=['medv'],
              x_vars=dftrain.columns[:-1])
```

This is the plot:
[image: This is the plot]

Answer (score 2):

The shape of a `pairplot` can't be changed.  But, you can create a similar `relplot` if you convert the dataframe to long form.

Here is some simple example code, starting from dummy data:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(300, 14), columns=[*"abcdefghijklmn"])
df_long = df.melt(id_vars=df.columns[-1], value_vars=df.columns[:-1])

g = sns.relplot(df_long, x=df.columns[-1], y='value', col='variable', col_wrap=4, height=2)
```

[image: sns.relplot]

Comment: Thank you, I have this problem, why it looks like this? https://ibb.co/j5HXc1r

Comment: Maybe you want to exchange the x and y axis? And/or remove x sharing? `g = sns.relplot(df_long, x='value', y=df.columns[-1], col='variable', col_wrap=4, height=2, facet_kws={'sharex': False})`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) and set a value of the parameter `col_wrap`.

> col_wrap (int): “Wrap” the column variable at this width, so that the
> column facets span multiple rows. Incompatible with a row facet.

Try this :

```
cols= dftrain.columns[:-1].tolist()

g = sns.FacetGrid(pd.DataFrame(cols), col=0, col_wrap=3, sharex=False)

for ax, varx in zip(g.axes, cols):
    sns.scatterplot(data=dftrain, x=varx, y="medv", ax=ax)
    
g.tight_layout()
```

##### # Output :

[image]